# how to use relationship with array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

hello i created a site with laravel and. my table post related with category with id.
like this

```sql
table post
  id
  title
  category_id

table category
  id
  name
  desc
```

and i want to showing a archive from post with the category, so i need to get all post from database. but i don`t know how to get category by `category_id` in post table

i know the all data come from database as array and i don`t know how to create a relationship to get category name from the id in post table

i have a model for post `Post` and category `Category` and controller `PostController` and `CategoryController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Eloquent Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) for this.

In the `Category` Class, you need to define a relation like below:

```
public function posts()
{
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Then, you can retrieve all the posts for a given category, by calling `posts()` method. For example, to get all posts for `category Id = 1`, you can do this:

```
Category::find(1)->posts
```

Similarly, in the `Post` class, you can create `categor()` method

```
public function category()
{
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

**To get all the categories from all the posts**

(1) Then you can use Laravel collection to find all category names for all the posts. Like this:

```
App\Post::all()->map->category->pluck('name')->unique()
```

Note, in the above line, I am taking advantage of Collection's `map` method to create a higher order construct to loop through all the posts.

(2) To show it in view, from your controller, first return the view

```
public function index()
{
  $categories = App\Post::all()->map->category->pluck('name')->unique();
  return view('index', compact('categories');
}
```

(3) **Showing the data in Blade** Inside the `index.blade.php`, show the values like this:

```
@foreach($categories as $c)
{{ $c }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i want to extract all category name for all post. for this must create a loop and this code must come in. bu i don`n know how to showing this in view blade

Comment: check my revised answer